Inserting a new title in an existing slide title
I just want to replace existing individual slide titles of a presentation by new titles simply listed in each line of a plain text file.
I managed to write something with help of AI, but I cannot insert the new title in the title of the slide. This loop is the issue:
 // Insert titles into each slide
for (let i = 0; i < titles.length && i < slides.length; i++) {
  const slide = slides[i];
  const placeholder = slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.TITLE);
  Logger.log(`Slide ${i + 1}: ${placeholder ? "Placeholder found" : "No placeholder"}`);

  if (placeholder) {
    // If placeholder exists, set its text
    placeholder.asShape().setText(titles[i]);
  } else {
    // Insert a text box if no title placeholder is found
    slide.insertTextBox(titles[i]);
  }

I get an error placeholder.asShape().setText is not a function.
How can I insert the new text in the title shape ?
Thanks, and sorry I am new to this.
Here is the complete script:
function insertTitlesIntoSlides() {
  const textFileName = "Titles.txt";  // Name of your text file
  const presentationName = "Presentation";  // Name of your Google Slides file without .pptx

  try {
    // Locate text file in Google Drive
    const textFileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(textFileName);
    if (!textFileIterator.hasNext()) {
      throw new Error('Text file not found. Please check the file name and ensure it is in Google Drive.');
    }

    // Retrieve content from text file
    const textFile = textFileIterator.next();
    const content = textFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    const titles = content.split('\n').filter(Boolean); // Split by lines and remove empty lines

    // Locate presentation in Google Drive
    const presentationIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(presentationName);
    if (!presentationIterator.hasNext()) {
      throw new Error('Presentation not found. Please check the presentation name.');
    }

    const presentationFile = presentationIterator.next();
    const presentationId = presentationFile.getId();
    const presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
    const slides = presentation.getSlides();

 // Insert titles into each slide
for (let i = 0; i < titles.length && i < slides.length; i++) {
  const slide = slides[i];
  const placeholder = slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.TITLE);
  Logger.log(`Slide ${i + 1}: ${placeholder ? "Placeholder found" : "No placeholder"}`);

  if (placeholder) {
    // If placeholder exists, set its text
    placeholder.asShape().setText(titles[i]);
  } else {
    // Insert a text box if no title placeholder is found
    slide.insertTextBox(titles[i]);
  }
}

    Logger.log('Titles have been successfully added to the slides.');
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

The input text file is "Titles.txt" with any plain text of n lines. Here are 8 lines for instance:
2-053-2 - Jeaot Isabelle
2-059-2 - Bufrère Jéremy
2-059-3 - Bufrère Jéremy
2-060-1 - Dillbecq Anthon
2-060-2 - Dilbecq Anthon
2-062-1 - Duois Anae
2-062-2 - Duois Anae
2-063-1 - Duois Fredue
The input presentation is "Presentation" , with any Google slides presentation with n slides.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Provide your sample slides with your expected output. You may use this Make an anonymous sample document

I tried your code, and it works for me. Upon testing, the code executed without generating a placeholder.asShape().setText is not a function error.

Ok thanks. I may simply then have not defined the title type correctly in the slides. I modified the script now to write in the first text box that it finds on the slide and it works.
